# Delete whitespace left and right in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, hotkeys, whitespace

In Notepad++, is there a hotkey to wipe all white space left and right of the cursor?

I'd imagine it would be the same as "delete current word", but I can't find it.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> deletes to the end of the word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes to the beginning of the word

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no shortcut by default, but you can easily add one using the shortcut mapper. The action to remove leading and trailing space is found in Edit > Blank operations > 
Remove leading and trailing space

You can map it by going to Settings > Shortcut Mapper... > Then scrolling to whichever one you want (such as 29) and double clicking on the cell under Shortcut.

Comment: "Remove leading and trailing space" drops those from the **whole** document, which is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find the actions you've asked for,
but could suggest a simple search-and-replace pattern:

Search: `\h+(\w+)\h+`
Replace: `_$1_` (the '_' character here represents a blank character)

You could also write a short macro for that -
see here for a list of predefined Notepad++ shortcut-keys:

[**Lists of default mouse and keyboard shortcuts for Notepad++ and some plugins**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)